# JavaFX Spring WebSocket send recieve Text & binary message

Tags: javafx, spring-websocket

I am first time developing JavaFX application for learning purpose. I have written spring web socket and want to send receive both binary(Images, text & pdf tec) & text messages. Both text & binary message received at server end but not received at client end. Please guide me what I am doing wrong.

Code References:
https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/BinaryWebSocket/binaryWebSocket.html#section1
https://developer.vonage.com/ja/blog/create-websocket-server-spring-boot-dr

**WebSocket code**

```
package com.simplews.handler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.socket.BinaryMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.CloseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.socket.PongMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.AbstractWebSocketHandler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.TextWebSocketHandler;

public class CustomWebSocketHandler extends AbstractWebSocketHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomWebSocketHandler.class);

    private final List<WebSocketSession> sessions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        sessions.add(session);
        super.afterConnectionEstablished(session);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        sessions.remove(session);
        super.afterConnectionClosed(session, status);
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        super.handleTextMessage(session, message);
        sessions.forEach(webSocketSession -> {
            try {
                webSocketSession.sendMessage(message);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Error occurred.", e);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void handleBinaryMessage(WebSocketSession session, BinaryMessage message) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("New Binary Message Received");
        session.sendMessage(message);
    }
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession session, WebSocketMessage<?> message) throws Exception {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage textMessage) {
            handleTextMessage(session, textMessage);
        }
        else if (message instanceof BinaryMessage binaryMessage) {
            handleBinaryMessage(session, binaryMessage);
        }
        else if (message instanceof PongMessage pongMessage) {
            handlePongMessage(session, pongMessage);
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected WebSocket message type: " + message);
        }
    }
}
```

**JavaFX Code**

```
package com.client;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import jakarta.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import jakarta.websocket.ContainerProvider;
import jakarta.websocket.DeploymentException;
import jakarta.websocket.OnClose;
import jakarta.websocket.OnMessage;
import jakarta.websocket.OnOpen;
import jakarta.websocket.Session;
import jakarta.websocket.WebSocketContainer;

@ClientEndpoint
public class JavaFXBinaryWsClient extends Application {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(JavaFXBinaryWsClient.class.getName());
  private ImageView imageView;
  private Session session;

  @OnOpen
  public void onOpen(Session session) {
    this.session = session;
  }

  @OnMessage
  public void onMessage(InputStream input) {
    System.out.println("WebSocket message Received!!!");
    Image image = new Image(input);
    imageView.setImage(image);
  }

  @OnClose
  public void onClose() {
    connectToWebSocket();
  }

  @Override
  public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
    connectToWebSocket();

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Send Image!");
    btn.setPrefSize(400, 27);
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        selectAndSendImage(primaryStage);
      }
    });
    imageView = new ImageView();
    imageView.setFitHeight(400);
    imageView.setFitWidth(400);
    imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
    imageView.setSmooth(true);

    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();

    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(btn, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(btn, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(btn, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(imageView, 27.0);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(imageView, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(imageView, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(imageView, 0.0);

    root.getChildren().add(btn);
    root.getChildren().add(imageView);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 427);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Image push!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  private void selectAndSendImage(Stage stage) {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Select Image to Send");
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
    try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
            OutputStream output = session.getBasicRemote().getSendStream()) {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int read;
      while ((read = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, read);
      }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }

  private void connectToWebSocket() {
    WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
    try {
      URI uri = URI.create("ws://localhost:8080/web-socket");   //BinaryWebSocketServer/images");
      container.connectToServer(this, uri);
    } catch (DeploymentException | IOException ex) {
      LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      System.exit(-1);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your `JavaFXBinaryWsClient extends Application`.  Which is probably not what you want.  The JavaFX launcher creates the JavaFX application, not Spring.  Therefore Spring is not processing the launched instance and all of those Spring annotations in your client class will not work.

Answer (score 1):

##### Example for STOMP over WebSockets with Java and JavaScript clients

Here is an example you can study.

It uses [STOMP](https://stomp.github.io) over web sockets rather than native websockets. I recommend using and learning STOMP rather than raw websockets, as STOMP is a higher level, more application developer-friendly protocol than coding directly to websockets.

It may not be what you want, but you are trying to learn anyway.  If you want, you can adapt it yourself to exactly what you want as part of your learning process (or you can just ignore it).

It uses a STOMP websocket server in Spring to send and receive text messages.  It provides two clients for the server, one a HTML client shown in a JavaFX WebView, the other a native JavaFX client.  Both clients are subscribing to the same STOMP topic, so, if both are connected, they will see the responses to the messages sent by the other clients.

The example does not also handle binary data like images (it is complicated and large enough without that).  I'll leave extending handling of the example for images as an exercise for the reader.

It is complicated enough that it would be better in git, but I'll just dump the code here for now.

##### Resources

If you need to understand how this works, I refer you to:

- [The Spring documentation on Websockets and Stomp.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/websocket/stomp.html)
- [The Spring tutorial on websockets](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) where most of the ideas (and some of the code) was lifted from.
  **Read this tutorial if you want to understand this answer better.**
- [Adding Spring Dependency Injection in JavaFX (JPA Repo, Service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887944/adding-spring-dependency-injection-in-javafx-jpa-repo-service)
- [Spring STOMP client documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/websocket/stomp/client.html)
- [Info on STOMP](https://stomp.github.io)

##### How the example works

You can think of the app like this, you (the client) are going to a party and arrive at the door.  The greeter (the server) asks your name, then makes an announcement out loud to everybody else at the party (all the other clients).  The announcement is a greeting with your name in it.

Native Java and JavaFX STOMP websocket client UI.

[image: JavaFX Client]

HTML/JavaScript STOMP websocket client UI in a WebView.

[image: WebView Client]

##### Example code

You need some classes to model messages.

A hello request message sent from clients to the server.

```
package org.example.fxspringwebsocket.model;

public record HelloMessage(String name) {}
```

A greeting response message sent by the server to the clients.

```
package org.example.fxspringwebsocket.model;

public record GreetingMessage(String content) {}
```

A server that handles the greeting announcements:

```
package org.example.fxspringwebsocket.server;

import org.example.fxspringwebsocket.model.GreetingMessage;
import org.example.fxspringwebsocket.model.HelloMessage;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public GreetingMessage greeting(HelloMessage message) {
        return new GreetingMessage("Hello, " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.name()) + "!");
    }
}
```

A client that sends the hello messages and listens for the greeting responses, keeping knowledge of all greetings that it has heard and the connection status it has to the server (e.g. whether the client is currently attending the party).

This example is a JavaFX client.  I will also provide a JavaScript example later.

The `send` method is where the client sends a message (the name of the person to greet) to the server and the `handleFrame` method is where the client accepts the server responses (the announced greetings) that are published on a topic on which the client has invoked `subscribe`.  When a response comes from the server a `Platform.runLater` call is made to update an observable list on the JavaFX thread, so there will be no multi-threading issues, similarly for maintaining connection status using a `connected`
observable boolean property.

```
package org.example.fxspringwebsocket.client;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import org.example.fxspringwebsocket.model.GreetingMessage;
import org.example.fxspringwebsocket.model.HelloMessage;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompCommand;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSession;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSessionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class StompClient implements StompSessionHandler {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StompClient.class);

    private static final String ENDPOINT_URL = "ws://localhost:8080/gs-guide-websocket";
    private StompSession stompSession;

    private final ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper connected = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(false);
    private final ObservableList<GreetingMessage> greetings = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ObservableList<GreetingMessage> getGreetings() {
        return greetings;
    }

    public ReadOnlyBooleanProperty connectedProperty() {
        return connected.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public void connect() {
        WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();

        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());

        try {
            stompSession = stompClient
                    .connectAsync(ENDPOINT_URL, this)
                    .get(); // this makes the async connection synchronous for easy programming, but it would be better off being handled asynchronously.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Connection failed.", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
        log.info(
                """
                Connection to STOMP server established
                Session: {}
                Headers: {}""", session.getSessionId(), connectedHeaders
        );

        subscribe("/topic/greetings");

        Platform.runLater(() -> connected.set(true));
    }

    public void subscribe(String topic) {
        log.info("Subscribing to topic {} for session {}", topic, stompSession.getSessionId());
        stompSession.subscribe(topic, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
        GreetingMessage greeting = (GreetingMessage) payload;
        log.info("Received message: {}", greeting.content());
        Platform.runLater(() -> greetings.add(greeting));
    }

    @Override
    public void handleException(StompSession session, StompCommand command, StompHeaders headers, byte[] payload, Throwable exception) {
        log.info("Exception in stomp session", exception);

        Platform.runLater(() -> connected.set(false));
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(StompSession session, Throwable exception) {
        log.error("Retrieved a transport error:", exception);

        Platform.runLater(() -> connected.set(false));
    }

    @Override
    public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
        return GreetingMessage.class;
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        if (stompSession != null) {
            log.info("Disconnecting from  stomp session {}", stompSession.getSessionId());
            stompSession.disconnect();
        }

        Platform.runLater(() -> connected.set(false));
    }

    public void send(HelloMessage helloRequest) {
        stompSession.send("/app/hello", helloRequest);
    }
}
```

The client needs a UI to collect the name to greet and to display the list of greetings that have been made.

```
package org.example.fxspringwebsocket.ui;

import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import org.example.fxspringwebsocket.client.StompClient;
import org.example.fxspringwebsocket.model.GreetingMessage;
import org.example.fxspringwebsocket.model.HelloMessage;

public class FXClientUI {
    private final StompClient stompClient;

    public FXClientUI(StompClient stompClient) {
        this.stompClient = stompClient;
    }

    public Node getUI() {
        TextField name = new TextField();

        Button connect = new Button("Connect");
        connect.setOnAction(e -> {
            stompClient.connect();
            name.requestFocus();
        });
        connect.disableProperty().bind(stompClient.connectedProperty());

        Button disconnect = new Button("Disconnect");
        disconnect.setOnAction(e -> stompClient.disconnect());
        disconnect.disableProperty().bind(stompClient.connectedProperty().not());

        Button send = new Button("Send");
        send.setOnAction(e -> {
            stompClient.send(new HelloMessage(name.getText()));
            name.textProperty().set("");
            name.requestFocus();
        });
        send.disableProperty().bind(
                name.textProperty().isEmpty()
                        .or(stompClient.connectedProperty().not())
        );
        send.setDefaultButton(true);

        Pane spacer = new Pane();
        spacer.setPrefWidth(30);

        HBox inputFields = new HBox(
                10,
                new Label("WebSocket connection:"),
                connect,
                disconnect,
                spacer,
                new Label("Who should I greet?"),
                name,
                send
        );
        inputFields.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);

        ListView<GreetingMessage> greetings = createGreetingsView();

        VBox layout = getLayout(inputFields, greetings);

        return layout;
    }

    private VBox getLayout(
            HBox inputFields,
            ListView<GreetingMessage> greetings
    ) {
        VBox layout = new VBox(
                10,
                inputFields,
                new Label("Greetings"),
                greetings
        );
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        return layout;
    }

    private ListView<GreetingMessage> createGreetingsView() {
        ListView<GreetingMessage> greetings = new ListView<>(
                stompClient.getGreetings()
        );

        greetings.setCellFactory(p -> new ListCell<>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(GreetingMessage item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                setText(
                        item != null && !empty
                                ? item.content()
                                : null
                );
            }
        });
        return greetings;
    }
}
```

The spring message broker needs to be configured to listen at an endpoint and host the greetings topic.

```
package org.example.fxspringwebsocket;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket");
    }
}
```

You need a Spring application

```
package org.example.fxspringwebsocket;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class StompSpringApplication {}
```

And a JavaFX application.  The JavaFX application has two tabs for two different types of clients, one is an HTML client in a WebView the other is a Java client displayed using a JavaFX UI.

```
package org.example.fxspringwebsocket;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.example.fxspringwebsocket.client.StompClient;
import org.example.fxspringwebsocket.ui.FXClientUI;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

public class StompFXApplication extends Application {
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
    private StompClient stompClient;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(
                StompSpringApplication.class,
                getParameters().getRaw().toArray(new String[0])
        );

        stompClient = new StompClient();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Tab webViewTab = new Tab("WebView Client");
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().load(
                "http://localhost:8080"
        );
        webViewTab.setContent(webView);

        Tab fxViewTab = new Tab("JavaFX Client");
        FXClientUI fxClientUI = new FXClientUI(stompClient);
        fxViewTab.setContent(fxClientUI.getUI());

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane(
                webViewTab, fxViewTab
        );

        tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(fxViewTab);
        tabPane.setPrefSize(1000, 400);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(tabPane));
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        stompClient.disconnect();

        // closing the context in this way will create message delivery exception warnings in the log for open STOMP connections.
        // a nicer implementation would disconnect the STOMP server more gracefully (which I don't know how to do at the moment),
        // but just ignore the logged warnings on shutdown for now . . .
        springContext.close();
    }
}
```

For the JavaScript client the files need to be in the `resources/static` folder.

There are some CSS styles in `main.css` for the JavaScript client.

```
body {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

#main-content {
    max-width: 940px;
    padding: 2em 3em;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

There is some HTML in `index.html` for the JavaScript UI.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello WebSocket</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@stomp/stompjs@7.0.0/bundles/stomp.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript><h2 style="color: #ff0000">Seems your browser doesn't support Javascript! Websocket relies on Javascript being
    enabled. Please enable
    Javascript and reload this page!</h2></noscript>
<div id="main-content" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="connect">WebSocket connection:</label>
                    <button id="connect" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Connect</button>
                    <button id="disconnect" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" disabled="disabled">Disconnect
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">What is your name?</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name here...">
                </div>
                <button id="send" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table id="conversation" class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Greetings</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="greetings">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And there is some JavaScript to implement the client logic used by the HTML client in `app.js`.  You can compare this with the Java `StompClient` application if you wish.

```
const stompClient = new StompJs.Client({
    brokerURL: 'ws://localhost:8080/gs-guide-websocket'
});

stompClient.onConnect = (frame) => {
    setConnected(true);
    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', (greeting) => {
        showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
    });
};

stompClient.onWebSocketError = (error) => {
    console.error('Error with websocket', error);
};

stompClient.onStompError = (frame) => {
    console.error('Broker reported error: ' + frame.headers['message']);
    console.error('Additional details: ' + frame.body);
};

function setConnected(connected) {
    $("#connect").prop("disabled", connected);
    $("#disconnect").prop("disabled", !connected);
    if (connected) {
        $("#conversation").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#conversation").hide();
    }
    $("#greetings").html("");
}

function connect() {
    stompClient.activate();
}

function disconnect() {
    stompClient.deactivate();
    setConnected(false);
    console.log("Disconnected");
}

function sendName() {
    stompClient.publish({
        destination: "/app/hello",
        body: JSON.stringify({'name': $("#name").val()})
    });
}

function showGreeting(message) {
    $("#greetings").append("<tr><td>" + message + "</td></tr>");
}

$(function () {
    $("form").on('submit', (e) => e.preventDefault());
    $( "#connect" ).click(() => connect());
    $( "#disconnect" ).click(() => disconnect());
    $( "#send" ).click(() => sendName());
});
```

Everything is built by Maven using JavaFX 21.0.1 and OpenJDK 21.0.1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>fxspringwebsocket</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>fxspringwebsocket</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <javafx.version>21.0.1</javafx.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

It is a non-modular application, as that is what works best with Spring.  To run it you need to provide a path to the JavaFX modules (either the ones in Maven or the ones in the JavaFX SDK lib directory) and add the required modules (`javafx.web`) using VM options (or use a JDK like BellSoft or Azul JDKs that include JavaFX).

```
-p <pathto>/javafx-sdk-21.0.1/lib --add-modules javafx.web
```

The class to run is:

```
org.example.fxspringwebsocket.StompFXApplication
```

The code is meant as tutorial code not as robust production code (in particular the code will generate errors on shutdown due to unclosed websocket connections, which can be ignored for tutorial purposes).

Comment: sure will follow whatever u suggested.

Comment: Now I am getting text message from both client & server. but binary message getting at server end not client end.from server I am sending to all clients as `private final List<WebSocketSession> subscribers = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

protected void handleBinaryMessage(WebSocketSession session, BinaryMessage message) throws IOException {
  subscribers.forEach(webSocketSession -> {
   try {
    webSocketSession.sendMessage(message);
   } catch (IOException e) {
   }
  });
 }`

Comment: As I noted in this answer "The example does not also handle binary data like images (it is complicated and large enough without that)."  That is still true and I don't intend to change that.

Comment: As a hint, the approach you have for binary message is using raw websockets, which is not what I suggested.  At least for images, I would not send them as binary data.  Instead, I would [encode the image into a jpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054672/writing-javafx-scene-image-image-to-file) using SwingFXUtils, then into a [RFC 2397 data scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054672/writing-javafx-scene-image-image-to-file), then it is text data and can be transported using the method in my answer.  The JavaFX 21+ image constructor can directly decode RFC 2397 data.