# SwingFXUtils alternative for Image serialization (Javafx, Swing, Raspberry Pi)

Tags: java, swing, javafx, raspberry-pi, arm

One of the use cases of my JavaFX application is to load an image on one side, serialize it over a TCP socket to show it as JavaFX image on the other side.

To implement this I am using `SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage()` and `SwingFXUtils.toFXImage()` to create and read a `BufferedImage` which can be serialized.

Everything is working. But I would like to run the displaying side on a raspberry pi. As I found out, there is no integration of Swing components in JavaFX on ARM, so I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` when using `SwingFXUtils` on a `Raspi`.

Please suggest how I can create and read a serializable image object without the use of `SwingFXUtils`?

Comment: Rather then serialising the `BufferedImage` object, just send the raw image data and don't care

Comment: `BufferedImage` isn't `Serializable` as-is, so you probably use some specialized serialization already, like `ImageIO.write(..)` (ie. you write the image in a common file format). If that is the case, then you can simply read it back on the Pi using `new Image(inputstream)`. No need for `SwingFXUtils`. PS: It might help with some code, and the stack trace you get (what class is not found?).

Comment: PS: I once wrote a quick PoC for an [JavaFX/ImageIO bridge](https://github.com/haraldk/FX-IIO), that avoids `SwingFXUtils` altogether (for better memory usage/performance). You can try, but I suspect you'll have the same `NoClassDefFoundError`...

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your Answers.

@haraldK of course i have written my `BufferedImage` to a `ByteArray` before serialization. My explanation last night wasn't exact enough. Mea culpa.

I found a solution for my problem: To make it work on a Raspberry Pi I just substituted `BufferedImage` with an `InputStream` to read my `ByteArray` containing the image data. This allowed me to create the JavaFX `Image` object with an `InputStream` instead of using `SwingFXUtils`.

**Before:**

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageUpdate.getImageByteArray()));

imageView.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null));
```

, where `imageUpdate` is an `ImageUpdate` Object used for data transport over TCP sockets (containing image and additional data).

As described before, this produces

```
Exception in thread "..." java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel
```

on the Raspberry Pi because of missing Swing Classes in JavaFX Port for ARM architecture.

**After:**

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageUpdate.getImageByteArray());

imageView.setImage(new Image(inputStream));
```

This solution works now like a charm on my Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

The source code of the missing class SwingFXUtils seems to be at :

http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~ant/RT-37740/webrev.0/modules/swing/src/main/java/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.java.html

It's GPL licensed. I tried it and it works on the raspberry PI