# JavaFX graph in a itext pdf document

Tags: java, javafx, itext

Im facing the following task:

I get some data (does not matter how) and have to generate a report in pdf format. My program in general has a GUI made with JavaFX, but the pdf part does run in a separate thread. In general the pdf creation is no problem. I' using **iText** as pdf lib.

The problem is, that I have to include a quite complex graph in the pdf document. The graph itself is also no problem, since I'm quite familiar with JavaFX's charts.

Currently I'm planning to tackle the chart problem like that:

```
// at first create the chart
final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
final LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

// format the graph and add the data
...not shwon here, not important...

// now get the chart as picture to embed in the document
WritableImage chartWrtImg                   = chart.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try {

    // convert the WritableImage from javaFX to an Image from itext
    ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(chartWrtImg, null), "png", byteArrayOutputStream);
    Image graphImg = Image.getInstance(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());

    // scale and position the picture
    graphImg.setAbsolutePosition(35, docHeight - 460);
    graphImg.scaleAbsolute(docWidth - 80, 350);

    // the itext pdf document
    document.add(graphImg);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

At the moment I get the following Exception when running the pdf creation:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils
```

Why do I get the shown exception? I' importing JavaFX version 13 via maven. The libs should be there (and are working on the Application thread as well).

Is it in general a smart approach to use a JavaFX chart like that just to create a graph for a pdf document?

Comment: have u tried with the `Image` class as sugested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50900945/swingfxutils-alternative-for-image-serialization-javafx-swing-raspberry-pi

Comment: Are you saying the `ClassNotFoundException` is only thrown when the code is executed on a non-FX thread? Is your application using custom `ClassLoader`s/`ModuleLayer`s? Have you added the `javafx.swing` module?

Comment: Currently I'm running the code NOT on the FX-thread, I'm not using custom ClassLoaders or anything and the import is present. ```import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;```

Comment: Can it work in general to use JavaFX Objects in a non-FX-thread, or do I have to spawn a FX-thread, just to use a chart, that I only want to embed in a pdf document?

Comment: Some JavaFX UI objects must always be used solely on the FX thread (e.g. `Stage`, `WebView`), but other such objects can be created and used on any thread (e.g. most subclasses of `Node`) as long as they are not part of a window that is showing. In any case, a `ClassNotFoundException` is not an exception I would expect to see if this was a threading issue—especially since neither you nor (I assume?) a library/framework is using custom `ClassLoader`s. Can you create a [mre] demonstrating the example and [edit] it into your question, please?

Comment: Okay I've discarded the idea to work with an image. I've worked out an alternative solution using a JFreeChart chart. This graph can be brought to the pdf with:
```chart.draw(g, r2D, new Point2D.Double(0,0));```
with g being a PdfGraphics2D object from the pdf writer, and r2D a Rectangle2D.Double.
This is much nicer, text can be formatted exactly like in the rest of the document.
Is there a similar approach for a FXChart?